# My account as a block

Tags: 7, theming

I am using Drupal 7. I want to show my account page as a block, where user can edit their personal information. Does anybody have an idea regarding this. Do I need to write custom module? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly you can try this :

1. Create a views block with current uid in contextual filter & have all the account fields in that views block
2. Use 'editablefields' module & make use of it for Inline Edit
3. Enable the block where you need

Hope it helps